# Redirect links using php

Tags: php

I have a database table which contains 100s of affiliate links and wanted to create a redirect  page to hide my affiliate links. What would be the best way to do this? I would like to redirect these 100s of links all at once without having to do each link one by one.

Comment: This is a bit of a broad question; have you tried anything thus far?

Comment: Before you do it, read this: https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/2721217?hl=en

Comment: I have not tried anything yet as i am not sure how to go about creating a script to create redirecting links.

Comment: Are you speaking about shortened URLs? Like `goo.gl/AbCdEf`?

Comment: for example a link which would go from my website http://mywebsite.com/go/id=1 which would redirect to a external affiliate link  http://affiliatelink.com/qwnmalin

Comment: Where are you stuck?  On how to perform a redirect in PHP?  A cursory Google search actually provides a lot of examples for that...

Comment: i am unable to find a way to redirect 100s of links all at once.

Answer (score 2):

Store the UNIQUE affiliate link ID with link in the table.

Create a PHP page and get the id by, $_GET['id']. Match this URL to the pattern `go/id=[0-9]`.

Query your database and get the link, `SELECT link FROM table WHERE id='$_GET['id']'`.

Use PHP redirect, to your affiliate link.

```
<?php
header("location: $affiliate_link"); // $affiliate_link is the variable where your link is stored after the query
?>
```